# Can someone please give an example of an extraordinarily narrow situation?

Tags: discussion

One of the reasons for closing is that a post is too localized.

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or
>   **an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet**. For help making this
>   question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Can anybody post an example of an extraordinarily narrow situation? Just need something to compare against.

Comment: Irreproducible software behavior is a classic example. When the O.P. cannot describe their problem in a way that enables others to reproduce it, and/or others cannot reproduce it (implying it likely results from some bad synergy with the whole system), and/or they write back and say "never mind, I fixed it" but won't explain further, then the question is too localized.  Another example is of temporal localization, such as questions about some transient or restricted event (a conference, a beta test program not open to everyone, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an example for you, but I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133574) explains the intent of the 'too localized' close vote.

Let me quote from it:

> Really, what matters most here is that first bit - "unlikely to ever
>   help future visitors". Everything is localized in some way, but if
>   your problem is so localized, so specific to this place, this time,
>   those people... that even if it is answered, the answer will never
>   again help anyone else... That's Too Localized.
>
> So... how 'bout we focus on that:
>
> ```
> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is so specific to you, right >here, right now that no one else will ever have the same problem or be able to benefit from its solution.
> ```

This [answer from Joel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415) also shines a light on the point behind too localized.

Comment: Thanks for the example :)

Answer (score 6):

Let me play devil's advocate here.  Like the devil, successful internet sites grow a [long tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail).  Sites like Amazon are successful because they offer highly localized (or specialized) products.  They do this by making the products easily discoverable.  **Before we remove a question for being too localized, we should consider how discoverable it is.**  Granted, it may be very localized - but if someone with that particular problem is able to find it with a Google search, we should not close it.

For example, while [Joel's example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415) might indeed be too localized:

> Why is there a green Honda Civic parked out in front of my house?

This question would not:

> Why is there a green Honda Civic VIN 895399345993234 parked out in
>   front of my house?

Someone who is missing a Honda might google the [VIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number) and find that information useful.

Comment: +1 on recognizing the Importance of the long tail.

Comment: Closed questions remain searchable: *e.g.*, Google still reports them.

Comment: @whuber I've always wondered about that. Why close a question at all since they remain to be searched? It seems to me that if a question is *XYZ-enough* to be closed, then it should also be deleted forever and ever, so it no longer clutters, and disappears from search results. I just don't understand what closing a question truly accomplishes besides preventing people from answering it.

Comment: @whuber - But if it gets closed and therefore not answered, what's the point of it being searchable and found by Google?